# Why can I not show images on my server?

Tags: image, http, tcp, webserver

I have made this code for class but I just can't figure out why it is that when I click on a link, it won't show me the .jpg or .mp4 file. I've been scouring the Internet and I've tried converting the image from CMYK to RGB, adding even more CRLF to the end of the file and I simply can't understand why it gives me this error:

"The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
or
"The mp4 file cannot be displayed because it is corrupted"

This is my "welcome page"

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Welcome to my server</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor=white>

   <p> Click one of the following: </p>
   <p> <a href="candyplease.jpg">Candy</a> </p>
   <p> <a href="moto.mp4">Rossi vs Stoner</a> </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class HTTPRequest implements Runnable
{
public static String CRLF = "\r\n"; // returning carriage return (CR) and a line feed (LF)

Socket socket;

// constructor
public HTTPRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception
{
    this.socket = socket;
}

// Implement the run() method of the Runnable interface.
// Within run(), we explicitly catch and handle exceptions with a try/catch statement.
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        processRequest();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private void processRequest() throws Exception
{
    //create an input and an output stream
    InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
    DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    // create a buffer
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));// reads the input data

    // Get the request line of the HTTP request message.
    String requestLine = buffRead.readLine();// get /path/file.html version of http

    // Display the request line.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(requestLine);
    // HERE WE NEED TO DEAL WITH THE REQUEST
    // Extract the filename from the request line.
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(requestLine);
    tokens.nextToken();
    String fileName = tokens.nextToken();

    //this is so that i don't have to write /front.html at the start
    if(fileName.equals("/")){
        fileName="/front.html";
    }
    // attach a "." so that file request is within the current directory.
    fileName = "." + fileName;

    // Open the requested file.

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean fileExists = true;
    try
    {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        fileExists = false;
    }

    // Construct the response message.
    String statusLine = null;
    String contentTypeLine = null;
    String entityBody = null;

    if (fileExists)
    {
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" + CRLF; // 200 success code
        contentTypeLine = "Content-type: " + contentType(fileName) + CRLF;
    }// content info

    else
    {
        contentTypeLine = "Content-type: text/html" + CRLF;// content info
        entityBody = "<HTML>" + "<HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>"
                + "<BODY>Not Found</BODY></HTML>";
        statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found" + CRLF;// 404 not found...
    }

    // Send the status line.
    outStream.writeBytes(statusLine);

    // Send the content type line.
    outStream.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);

    // Send a blank line to indicate the end of the header lines.
    outStream.writeBytes(CRLF);

    // Send the entity body.
    if (fileExists)
    {
        outStream.writeBytes(statusLine);// Send the status line.
        outStream.writeBytes("\n"+contentTypeLine);// Send the content type line.
        sendBytes(fis, outStream);
        fis.close();
    } else
    {
        outStream.writeBytes(statusLine);// Send the status line
        outStream.writeBytes("\n"+contentTypeLine);// Send the content type line.
        outStream.writeBytes(entityBody);// Send the an html error message info body.
    }

    System.out.println("*****");
    System.out.println(fileName);// print out file request to console
    System.out.println("*****");
    // Get and display the header lines.
    String headerLine = null;
    while ((headerLine = buffRead.readLine()).length() != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(headerLine);
    }

    // Close streams and socket.
    outStream.close();
    buffRead.close();
    socket.close();

}

// return the file types
private static String contentType(String fileName)
{
    if (fileName.endsWith(".htm") || fileName.endsWith(".html"))
    {
        return "text/html";
    }
    if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpeg"))
    {
        return "image/jpeg";
    }
    if (fileName.endsWith(".gif"))
    {
        return "image/gif";
    }
    if(fileName.endsWith(".mp4"))
    {
    return "movie"; 
    }
    return "application/octet-stream";

}

// set up i/o streams
private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream fis, DataOutputStream outStream)
        throws Exception
{
    // Construct a 1K buffer to hold bytes on their way to the socket.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes = 0;

    // Copy requested file into the socket's output stream.
    while ((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)// read() returns minus one, indicating that the end of the file
    {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        outStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
    }
}
```

}

Please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't get this line :

```
outStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
```

anyway, could you dump the post so that we could check what's going on ?

Comment: i asked everyone what to do and someone had the problem that they didn't have a carriage return line feed somewhere so i went ballistic and put that almost everywhere. it's probably something i forgot to take out. could you also tell me what "dumping the post" means?

Comment: i was pointing out to your last writeBytes which didn't really make sense to me as you are writing binary data. the "post" dump is to try to show me/us what your answer looks like , at lease the first 10 lines.

Comment: GET /candyplease.jpg HTTP/1.1
    *****./candyplease.jpg
*****
Host: 192.168.1.23:9999
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.1.23:9999/
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: That's the query from the browser, could you show the 10 first lines of your server answer please ? with all my thanks :)

Comment: Those are the return lines in the console. As I previously stated, on the browser, the front page works fine. However, upon clicking on "candyplease", I get a "the image could not be displayed because it contains errors" error.

Comment: ok, please move your last outStream.writeBytes("\r\n"); after the its next closing bracket, if it still doesn't work use fiddler on the client side to catch your server answer and see if your http answer is ok

Comment: ok installed fiddler, ran the client side, shows me the same things my console shows me but on the bottom left it says "not an image" which means something's definitely wrong.

Comment: please comment the two lines previous to your first sendBytes(fis, outStream);, they do not make sense either, as you already sent the corresponding headers

Comment: YES
THAT DID IT. THOSE TWO DAMN LINES. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: I wish I could repay you but I need 15 rep to give you upvotes.